# How to loop through list of google searches for web scraping

Tags: python, pandas, loops, web-scraping

I am currently trying to write a code that allows me to iterate through a list of google searches, for then to be scraping with beautifulsoup the relevant URL links of the google search and use pandas to extract a table within each URL link.

The last part seems to be working ok when I run one Google search at a time, but as I try to loop through a list of keywords, the following attribute error appears:

> *ResultSet object has no attribute 'findAll'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when
> you meant to call find()?*

The code runs through the first iteration but stops at the second for loop at the second iteration.

Any ideas on how to solve it?

```py
import time
import pandas as pd
import requests
#from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

mylist = [205085000, 205520000, 205545190, 205566030, 205622000]

filename = 'ShipInfo.csv'

TableHeader = 'Vessel Name; IMO number;  Vessel Type; Year Built; \n'
f = open(filename, 'w')
f.write(TableHeader)

for mmsi in mylist:
    
    print(mmsi)
    # Make two strings with default google search URL
    # 'https://google.com/search?q=' and
    # our customized search keyword.
    # Concatenate them
    mmsi_number = str(mmsi)
    
    web_page= "vesselfinder+"
    url = 'https://google.com/search?q=' + web_page + mmsi_number
    print(url)  
    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    
    #html parsing
    soup = soup(html, 'html.parser')
    
    #extract google search results containing "www.vesselfinders.com" 
    links = []
    for link in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
        
        if 'www.vesselfinder.com' in link.get('href'):
            links.append(link.get('href'))
    print('Total number of links from google are: ', len(links))
    
    #Request the url from the first google result       
    r = requests.get(links[0],  headers=headers)
    
    #use pandas to extract tables from the web page, and create a summary dictonary
    df = pd.read_html(r.text)
    ship = pd.concat([df[1], df[2]], ignore_index=True).set_index(0).to_dict()[1]
    
    print('The Ship was built in: ', ship['Year of Built'])
    

    
    f.write(ship['Vessel Name'] + '; ' + ship['IMO number'] + '; ' + ship['Ship type'] + '; ' +  ship['Year of Built'] + '\n')
    
f.close()
```

Comment: Welcome by SO - Please improve your question / code, it causes another error first.

Comment: It causes _several_ errors first. This question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870667/how-to-convert-an-html-table-to-an-array-in-python